# Send HTTP GET request to destination by IP address in java

Tags: java, get

I have an Apache web server launched on another computer in my local network, that have a .php file in its root folder, so I can send my requests from browser using addresses like "192.168.1.5/connect.php?param1=value1&param2=value2". I really need to do that from my java code (by using HttpUrlConnection), but by some reason it works only with url, not with the IP address, I mentioned above. Is there a way to make it work with IP instead of url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HttpUrlConnection` can be perfectly used for both hostname HTTP connections and for IP address HTTP connections:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://192.168.1.5/connect.php?param1=value1&param2=value2").openConnection();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I totally forgot that I should use "http://" prefix. Sorry for silly question and thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Please read and understand the URL syntax as described here https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt

Having said that, the http scheme allows hostnames or ip addresses.

http://192.168.1.5/connect.php?param1=value1&param2=value2

is a valid URL.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying, but my problem is that I can't send such requests from java code. If I had domain name like "website.com", I could use HttpUrlConnection to send such requests to server easily. But when I have to use IP address instead of domain name, HttpUrlConnection doesn't seem to work.